# Tools for faster code reading or understanding

Tags: windows, code-analysis

There is known ways of how to read code faster (e.g. see the reference first / find the root call / find the hub for components / etc.), but these are all human ways.

Is there any tools which help human to read and understand code faster?

For faster code reading, I mainly use

- Visual Assist - Find references
- Visual Studio - Find references, Show call hierarchy

The tool should run on Windows, and mainly cover C++. I don't set any limit on paid solutions. For now, I rely on *Find References* feature mostly, but there should be more that I have never imagined.

Features: Other than *Find References,* well... code flow highlighting (e.g. MIT Scratch)?

Comment: Perhaps look at [software visualization tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/software_visualization)?

Comment: @DavidCary The list of software in the web page you told me is quite helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the open source [Source Trail](https://www.sourcetrail.com/); if you like it, I could work up an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can visualize the structure of applications & libraries, pull out any documentation and have syntax highlighted & hyperlinked code views of the codebase by generating a document set with [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) and [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/).

If you tell Doxygen to process the source code, (in quite a long list of languages), and to include undocumented code, code fragments & where to find GraphViz then it can produce a set of html documentation, *(and several other formats),* that includes call graphs, inheritance diagrams, etc., where clicking on a function shows you the documentation and signature and has the option to show the syntax highlighted source code of that function.

Both of the above programs are:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform (Windows, Mac & Linux plus others)
- Available in multiple translations
- Have a lot of community support
- Work really well!
- Can be invoked from a batch file or as a part of a make process

Doxygen includes a GUI for configuration called DoxyWizard

Comment: The first thing I do on any new project is to run it through Doxygen - even if it doesn't have any Doxygen comments. An excellent suggestion!